# TypeError: unbound method classify() must be called with SAM instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)

Tags: python, classification

I am want to do SAM classification.For it i did code like this.

```
from pysptools.util import envi as ev
from pysptools.classification import SAM as sm
import numpy as np
import gdal
d=ev.load_ENVI_spec_lib("D:\data\speclib.hdr")
img=gdal.Open("D:\data\sub_66")
M=img.ReadAsArray()
n1=d[0]
n2=d[1]
n1=np.transpose(n1)
wavelength=n2['wavelength']
wavelength=np.float64(wavelength)
E=np.column_stack((wavelength,n1))
class1=sm.classify(M,E,thresold=0.1)
```

But it gives error like this

> TypeError: unbound method classify() must be called with SAM instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)

What is the problem?
M - is ndarray of hyperspectral image
E - is ndarray of spectral library consist 5 column(wavelength,spectra1,spectra2..spectra4)

Comment: I am not familiar with `pysptools`, but my general advice is to get `help(sm.classify)`  and check what parameters it expects.

Comment: You called a class method directly. Usually it is called from an instance of the class. You should create one first.

Comment: @ Klaus D-How?Please give example if possible.